# Multiple bootstrap css buttons, hide and expand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, expand

So i Have looked around and researched quite a bit before coming here, I am basically trying to implement bootstrap css buttons where when I click one a div will expand and when I click another the already open div will collapse and the new div will open. I have three buttons. The problem I am facing is that when I click the second button the div expands below the already open first div.

I have not included any Javascript (am quite new to JS) at the moment and have not seen it in other examples I have seen (like on the bootstrap website: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/).

My code is here:

```html
<button class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#corp">More+</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#wedding">More+</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#photo">More+</button>
<div class="sectioncont">
  <div id="corp" class="collapse">
    <h2>Wedding Ceremonies</h2>
    We work closely with our clients in order to ensure their strategy and message is aligned, from business objectives and brand values, to target audience and event format. We challenge thinking, perception and message; only then do we start developing
    and conceptualizing a bespoke event strategy and creative treatment. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>

  <div id="wedding" class="collapse">
    <h2>Wedding Ceremonies</h2>
    We work closely with our clients in order to ensure their strategy and message is aligned, from business objectives and brand values, to target audience and event format. We challenge thinking, perception and message; only then do we start developing
    and conceptualizing a bespoke event strategy and creative treatment. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>

</div>
```

Thanks and any help would be greatly appreciated. I am implementing this code worpdress platform with a default twentythirteen theme (using a child theme).
Amit

Comment: you need to use Accordion not Collapse

Comment: I edited the answer to add images also.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using bootstrap. you need to include the bootstrap's js like the:

> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js
>
> assets/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js

cause some of the **bootstrap components** only work when u have included the *js files*.

some of the components also have specific *js* on their own.

In the bootstrap component page of collapes, it's also said that:

> Collapse The Bootstrap collapse plugin allows you to toggle content on
> your pages with a bit of **JavaScript** and some classes. Flexible plugin
> that utilizes a handful of classes (from the required transitions
> plugin) for easy toggle behavior.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for you help here, how do I include the bootstrap .js mentioned into wordpress?

Comment: in Wordpress. i guess u dont need to add the js file. you can look for Boostrap plugins in Wordpress and add it to your site. try this https://wordpress.org/plugins/bootstrap-3-shortcodes/

Comment: Tried installing it and saw no change. How does it work in the first example given here: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#example

Comment: have u also tried to use the HTML of the first example sir?

Comment: I have tried using the example with the .collapse and .collapsing.

Comment: try looking of this one sir for they have used different code for the collapsing in the Wordpress . https://github.com/filipstefansson/bootstrap-3-shortcodes#collapse . they have documentation for everything here

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Accordion` instead of `Collapse`

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
<div class="container">

  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title"><button class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#corp">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">More+</botton></a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">   <h2>Wedding Ceremonies</h2>
We work closely with our clients in order to ensure their strategy and message is aligned, from business objectives and brand values, to target audience and event format. We challenge thinking, perception and message; only then do we start developing
and conceptualizing a bespoke event strategy and creative treatment. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<img src="http://lombardidental.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/smiley.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2"><button class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#corp">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">More+</botton></a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">     <h2>Wedding Ceremonies</h2>
We work closely with our clients in order to ensure their strategy and message is aligned, from business objectives and brand values, to target audience and event format. We challenge thinking, perception and message; only then do we start developing
and conceptualizing a bespoke event strategy and creative treatment. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<img src="http://lombardidental.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/smiley.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3"><button class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#corp">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">More+</botton></a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">New Div<img src="http://lombardidental.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/smiley.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div> 
</div>

</body>
```

You have to use `Accordion` instead of `Collapse`

Here's the working [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdZpVO) example

**EDIT:**

Working [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNydYX) example with images

Comment: Hi Thanks so much for providing this but the example does not open and close the divs when you press each button from what I am seeing? I tried implementing it also and did not find that it worked?

Comment: Oh right, yep thats what I am looking for. Let me play around with this and see if I can implement it into my website styling. Currently I have three images with the buttons "More+" below them. Hope I can incorporate all of this into the accordion style.

Comment: Also how do I incorporate the scripts into wordpress? I am using the plugins Bootstrap 3 Shortcodes and Easy Bootstrap Shortcode. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: @user2323469 yeah sure, it collapse along with the div. So anything within div will collapse accordingly

Comment: @user2323469 Check my answer i edited it, heres working codepen example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNydYX

Comment: Thanks so much! I will have to play around with this to get it into my website looking the way I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

With a slight modification to your DOM, this is an easy task with jQuery.

```html
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#corp">More+</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#wedding">More+</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#photo">More+</button>
    <div class="sectioncont">
        <h2>Wedding Ceremonies</h2>
      <div id="corp" class="collapse">
        We work closely with our clients in order to ensure their strategy and message is aligned, from business objectives and brand values, to target audience and event format. We challenge thinking, perception and message; only then do we start developing
        and conceptualizing a bespoke event strategy and creative treatment. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </div>

        <h2>Wedding Ceremonies</h2>
      <div id="wedding" class="collapse">
        We work closely with our clients in order to ensure their strategy and message is aligned, from business objectives and brand values, to target audience and event format. We challenge thinking, perception and message; only then do we start developing
        and conceptualizing a bespoke event strategy and creative treatment. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </div>

    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.collapse').hide();
});
$('button').click(function(){
  var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
  $('.collapse').each(function(a,b){
    if('#'+b.id !== target){
      $('#'+b.id).hide();
    }    
  });
  $(target).toggle();
});
   

 </script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much. How do I make it so when I click on the same button the div will also close?

Comment: I edited my answer to close the target if it is already open.

Comment: Wow this is really perfect. Thanks so much. Let me see how I can implement it to mine.

Comment: Hey, I almost have this working, I just wanted to ask (sorry I am a bit new at this) how do i add the line: <script src="https://ajax...."></script> to wordpress? Do I need to create another .js file with this or can I just write a statement like in HTML?

Comment: It is better to separate js into its own file, but it can be added to any HTML file.

Comment: Actually that line that includes jQuery should be in the HTML document before any scripts that use it.

Comment: For some reason it is working perfectly on the sample html you provided but on wordpress its not opening and closing after once being opened and its one button is not closing when another is pushed. Any idea why this might be? My code is exactly as you provided with the javascript you provided and the script in a seperate file (being called upon through functions.php)?

Comment: Try putting it directly after the HTML content as it is in my snippet.

Comment: I placed it directly into the HTML content (the scripts before the content) and it was the same result. Is there a conflict between WP? Tried placing it after also.

Comment: You may already have jQuery included with the theme, so try leaving that out, and see if you get errors in the console like $ is not a function. It may be a no-conflict version, try replacing all "$" with "jQuery", if you get error like jQuery is not a function, then jQuery is not there,  consult WordPress theme docs for how to add.

Comment: I am using the wordpress theme twentythirteen as my backbone. How do I go about checking for this? I could not find any mention in the parent functions.php file.